# Android Studio - remove Security Exception warning

Tags: android, android-studio, suppress-warnings, runtime-permissions

I'm getting the user's location through

```
Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
```

This line of code is inside a method and before calling this method I do check for Android run time permissions. Only if the permission is available from the user then I call this method. Code is working perfectly.

The problem is that Android Studio still shows an error on this line not recognising that I've already checked before calling this function.

```
Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential `SecurityException`
```

Now how do I remove this warning? I've already checked for permissions and don't want  to check again just to remove this warning. I've tried adding @SuppressWarnings() but don't know the exact String to pass into this.             **@SuppressWarnings({"all"})** works but it is obviously not recommended.

How do I remove this warning?

**EDIT 1 :** This is my exact code -

```
private void checkPermissions() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        getLocation();  //Method called if I have permission
}

private void getLocation() {
    //Android studio shows warning at this line.
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
}
```

But if I put the permission check inside getLocation() method then the warning disappears. **@SuppressWarnings({"MissingPermission"})** did not work.

**EDIT 2:** I've discovered that the only way to suppress the warning are -

Adding this comment on top of that particular piece of code -

```
//noinspection ResourceType
```

or adding this -

```
@SuppressWarnings({"ResourceType"})
```

Comment: If my edited answer bellow works, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Put `@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")` above your function implementation

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You are looking for (updated to improve clarity):

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings({"MissingPermission"})
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE == requestCode) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);


       }
}
```

**EDITED:**

The correct lint rule is **MissingPermission**, but there seems to be a bug that misplace it to some people.

So, please try *@SuppressWarnings({"ResourceType"})*, too.

Comment: Are you sure?

I updated my answer to best clarification. This code is parsed and compiling on my Android Studio (2.0-Preview 7) without any warning, from gradle or lint.

Comment: You have the permission declared on your manifest file too, right?

Comment: I have everything correct. Code works perfect. Just want to remove the warning. Check my edited question.

Comment: Is exactly what I'm saying. The line @SuppressWarnings({"MissingPermission"}) is removing the warning to me.

Comment: @Jyotman Singh, @SuppressWarnings({"ResourceType"}) works properly?

Comment: {"ResourceType"} is working but {"MissingPermission"} is not. -0-a

Comment: The incorrect annotation name working was due to a Google bug. I think both work now.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking to ignore this lint warning, you can either do this inline:

```
//noinspection MissingPermission
Location lastLocation = FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(locationClient);
```

or at method level:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"MissingPermission"})
public void toggleGPS(boolean enableGPS) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Android Studio Inspection To Generate 
`@SuppressWarnings({"MissingPermission"})` For Your Method Or Class

[image: android studio missing permission check]