# Requesting Location Permission at Runtime

Tags: android, location, android-6.0-marshmallow, lint, runtime-permissions

I have a query implementing `RuntimePermission` for `Location`. When I tried to `requestLocationUpdates`, I got `LintError` suggesting me to add `PermissionCheck` for that line. Considering that I implemented run-time permissions. So this is how it looks,

```
if (isNetworkEnabled() && networkListener != null) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]
                    {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);

        } else
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, networkListener);
}
```

And my main class implements `onRequestPermissionsResult` callback. This looks like,

```
switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_LOCATION:
                if (grantResults.length == 2 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, networkListener);
                } else
                    Message.displayToast(context, "Without enabling permission, you can't access this feature");
            break;
    }
```

After the permission is granted, I request location updates again. But it again shows `LintError` to add the `PermissionCheck`. Refer the below image

[image]

Just for try I `checkSelfPermission` before requesting for `requestLocationUpdate` inside `onRequestPermissionsResult` and the error is gone. Like below code.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permissions[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

So, my question is do I need to check the permission once again if the user granted the permission? Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: But why this is needed? After permission is granted, I'm requesting for update! Just trying to understand the use case.

Comment: Lint knows that any call that requires user permission must be wrapped around a permission check statement  and thus the Lint error. You can execute this program without any issue if you know that the exception won't be thrown.

Comment: I would put the permission check and location update logic inside a function named `checkAndCallLocationUpdates` and call it from the `onRequestPermissionResult`

Comment: I even tried by having a common function. But I have some local variables which cannot be acquired from `onRequestPermissionsResult` so I dropped it. But it was a query just to understand why it's like this. If this is the case I have to check it again. Thanks for your quick reply. Appreciate it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124794/android-studio-remove-security-exception-warning

Answer (score 2):

You do need to check for checkSelfPermission because with latest OS 6 (Marshmallow) you can revoke the permissions granted for an app by going into settings. 
So even if user has granted the permissions to app during installation time, at runtime you need to doublecheck whether your app still has the permissions or user has revoked those permissions.