# Request location update permission at run time

Tags: android, google-play-services

This line of code requires me to add a permission

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311514/requesting-location-permission-at-runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
    private static final int REQUEST = 112;


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
    {
        String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
            if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) 
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST );
            } else {
                getLocation();//call function
            }
    } else 
    {
             getLocation();//call function
    }
```

get Permissions Result

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        getLocation();//call function
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to send sms.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

check permissions  for marshmallow

```
    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

getLocation

```
    private void getLocation() 
    {
        .
        .
        .
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        .
        .
        .

    }
```