# Android Studio asking for permission check after permission checked

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions

maybe this is a stupid question but......

I would like to know why `Android Stuio` asks for permission check in a certain part of my code, even though I have already gone through the permission check some lines above...

I have enclosed a small screen cap with this part of the code to show you the exact situation...all the code that you can see on the picture is included in the only method existing in the code: `OnCreate`

[image]

Comment: This is asking because you are targeting app android M or higher. So some method that you need to check with if android.version>=M then {}else{...}

Comment: Firstly it is just a warning, not error. Also you should know that Android Stunio sometimes offers you wrong things. So first check if it is working, and only if it does not - start panic

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/35191441/2919811

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a warning generated by android studio. You code will still compile and run . But it is best practice to include the permission check before calling `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates`

Like:

```
     public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        String permission = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION";
        int res = this.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
        return (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }
```

use it like:

```
if (checkLocationPermission()) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 3000, 0, myLocationListener);
            }
```

Comment: oh ok, thanks, since it is in red I thought it is an error, I will check that and mark it as answer if all goes right